# Github - remove subfolder, move files down

Tags: git, github

Accidentally I pushed to my remote repo directory with all files - Rails app actually (of the same name as my repo). So now I have:

```
my_repo_name/my_repo_name/other_file
```

I want to `rename my_repo_name/my_repo_name` to `./my_repo_name`.
How can I do it? All is commited and pushed from my local repository and I have no idea how to change those files now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/1814/renaming/5929/rename-folders#t=201702071026023754187

Comment: I'm getting error: fatal: can not move directory into itself, source=my_repo_nme, destination=my_repo_name

Answer (score 0):

Go to your repository root directory (`my_repo_name`). Then move all files/folders inside `my_repo_name` to root of project directory. Now, do git add, commit & push.

```
$ mv my_repo_name/* .
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Move files & folder'
$ git push origin HEAD
```